# Send extra form data with Blueimp Jquery file upload Basic Plus UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp, asp.net-webpages

[image]

My file uploader is working fine and now I wanted to send selected value of the dropdown with uploading data when click `Start Upload`.

I read the following wiki, but had no luck.
[How to submit additional form data](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-Form-Data#adding-additional-form-data-programmatically)

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I am not near a smart as most of the folks on here, but I was trying to implement the same type of thing and got it to work for me. I might not be able to explain the why's very well, so hopefully someone can fill what I don't quite understand.

While my implementation is a little bit different, (I am going for two additional inputs per image) it might point you in the right direction.

Here is what I was trying to do... I wanted to use the form to add a file to a folder on there server as well as adding it to a database. Also, For each image I wanted to select to other fields to be added to the database as well.

As the documentation describes, I had to modify the form on the index page by adding my select tag in the form template. For simplicity sake I am only showing a basic select tag and a text field instead of the php filled select tags I will be using.

Ensure that you provide a name for the select Tag and include the [] after the name for each of the fields as well. It will be used in the /server/php/index.php.

```
    <td>
    <td class="title"><label>SizeID: <input name="sizeID[]" required></label></td>
    </td>
<td class="title"><label>Type: <select name="invTypeID[]">
                                        <option value="1">Thing one</option>
                                        <option value="2">Thing two</option>
                                    </select></label>
                                    </td>
    </td>
```

in the /server/php/index.php you will have to modify the

```
protected function handle_form_data()
```

and

```
protected function handle_file_upload()
```

For my particular implementation, I changed the handle_form_data function to the following. This enables the use of the two new fields in the form to be passed to the handle_file_upload function.

```
protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
    $file->sizeID = @$_REQUEST['sizeID'][$index];
    $file->invTypeID = @$_REQUEST['invTypeID'][$index];    
}
```

Next I modified the handle_file_upload to match the proper sql statement and adapted the bind_param() function to meet my needs as well.

```
protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
        $index = null, $content_range = null) {
    $file = parent::handle_file_upload(
        $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range
    );
    if (empty($file->error)) {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
            .'` (`imgID`, `sizeID`, `invTypeID`)'
            .' VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param(
            'sii',
            $file->name,
            $file->sizeID,
            $file->invTypeID
        );
        $query->execute();
        $file->id = $this->db->insert_id;
    }
    return $file;
}
```

I hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: After posting this I realized that in order to pull the data from anything other than the default table, you have to updated select statement  from the function set_additional_file_properties($file) function. Also be aware that the delete($print_response = true)  function might also have to be updated depending on your implementation as well.